# Develop a class a one-dimensional array and two instances of this class

Tags: arrays, oop

My task:

Create 2 class objects. Delete all elements in the first object that are contained in the second.

My implementation:

```
    class Vector

      def initialize
        @vector = Array.new
      end
   end

    vector1 = Vector.new(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    vector2 = Vector.new(3,6,7)
```

But this does not work as needed. What should I fix?

Comment: There is no `-` binary operator defined for `Vector` class. By the way, there's something else wrong. Your class, as written, would result in an error with `Vector.new(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is some sort of question from institute, and requirements are different than what you coded, I am just trying to correct your coding and rectify so you get some result, than you can further proceed to full-fill your requirements.

1. Your first mistake is you are asking for one parameter but providing
   commas is giving multiple parameters, so I have changed it to get
   array.
2. As changed array so now you can't add another array in first, as it
   is just one array so I am removing `<<` and adding `=` in initialize
   method
3. Your initialize method is not taking any parameter, but you are
   providing, but you have to define a method `set_vector` so you have
   to use that method instead of class, as per your requirement that is
   what you want.
4. You should define - method but than you have to play with class
   variables too, as you are playing with two object and with in your
   class you have to define `-` function, but I am here just using your
   get_vector method to compare arrays and return your response.
   changing put to print so you can have variables instead of all items.

Hope this will give you some helpful insight to coding.

```
class Vector

  def initialize
    @vector = Array.new
  end

  def set_vector=(vector)
    @vector = vector
  end

  def get_vector
    @vector
  end
end

def confront(first_vector, second_vector)
  first_vector.get_vector - second_vector.get_vector
end

first_vector = Vector.new
first_vector.set_vector=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
second_vector = Vector.new
second_vector.set_vector=[3,6,7]
final_vector = confront(first_vector, second_vector)

begin
puts "First:" 
print first_vector.get_vector
puts "\nSecond:"
print second_vector.get_vector
puts "\nFinal Vector:"
print final_vector
end
```